# remove the object if its field does not match with the other aray

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
let array = [
            {name: "60", origin: "tcs"},
            {name: "70", origin: "cfs"},
            {name: "80", origin: "ehg"},
    ]
undefined
let def = [
            {id: "60", testorigin: "tcs"},
            {id: null, testorigin: "cfs"},   // this line should be removed
            {id: "80", testorigin: "ehg"},
]
```

output

```js
[
    {name: "60", origin: "tcs"},
    {name: "80", origin: "ehg"},

]
```

I just want to remove the second element of def because its id is null and its not matching with the name of array.

tried many way, but I failed, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you matching only by `id` property?

Comment: yes it should match with name from array and id from def

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
let array = [
  {name: "60", origin: "tcs"},
  {name: "70", origin: "cfs"},
  {name: "80", origin: "ehg"},
 ];
 
 let def = [
  {id: "60", testorigin: "tcs"},
  {id: null, testorigin: "cfs"},
  {id: "80", testorigin: "ehg"},
];

const result = array.filter(item => def.map(d => d.id).includes(item.name));
console.log('Result: ', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is solution. you just need to check condition of both objects with same indexes.
this answer will help you.

```
for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    if(array[i].name == def[i].id){
        console.log(array[i])
    }
}
```

Thanks!